# Нужно чтобы на телефоне html изображение fullscreen можно было растянуть тачем

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

Мне нужно открывать на сайте изображение на полный экран мобилки.
Юзер кликает по нему и разворачивает.
Но вот беда,- когда оно fullscreen, его нельзя растянуть (приблизить) пальцами. На жесты не реагирует!
Как сделать чтобы реагировало?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes">
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="image" src="/path/to/image.jpg" style="width:100%;">
  </body>
  <script>
    function fullscreen() {
      var el = document.getElementById('image');
      if(el.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        el.webkitRequestFullScreen();
      } else {
        el.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } }            
    document.getElementById('image').addEventListener("click", fullscreen)
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Самому написать ответ событие на `touch`...? (Можно приближать через `scale`, а двигать через `translate` в пропорции `transform`)

Comment: Пробую. Да, вроде так работает. Но это как-то не по-феншую. И глючит страшно. Так пробую https://codepen.io/AbramPlus/pen/mdymKom